# External keyboard/mouse natural scrolling

Tags: keyboard, mouse

I am new to Ubuntu. I recently purchased a Jelly Comb keyboard/touchpad (model: WGJP-110) to use with my computer. I have found the settings for changing the scroll direction on my laptop (Acer Travelmate), but I can't figure out how to reverse the scroll direction on the external touchpad.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I don't see any problem with this question. Asking how to reverse the scroll direction in Ubuntu on a Ubuntu Q&A website is totally normal.

Comment: @TimSchumacher The question was migrated from StackOverflow

Comment: Oops, that doesn't seem to be shown in the Mobile App. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using one of the latest Ubuntu releases that uses libinput, you should be able to disable it by using `xinput`.

Try running these commands in terminal:

1. `xinput list`

   This will give you list of devices connected. Find the one you need to change settings on and note its id number.
2. `xinput list-props ID`

   Replace `ID` with the id of your device.  This command will give you a list of the device's options. Find the option "Natural Scrolling Enabled" and see if it has 0 or 1 value. 1 means it is active, 0 means it is inactive. You just need to revert it, i.e. set it to 0 if natural scrolling is activated.
3. `xinput --set-prop ID 'libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled' 0`

   This will disable natural scrolling on the device. Remember that `ID` in the example should be replaced with the id of your device.

If this solution works for you, you can make it permanent by adding it into your `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf` file. Open the file in your preferred text editor, with root privileges. E.g, run:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf
```

You should find content like this:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput pointer catchall"
        MatchIsPointer "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput keyboard catchall"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection
```

The section with `pointer` in the identifier is for mouse, the section with `keyboard` is for keyboard, the section with `touchpad` is for touchpad.

To make it set natural scrolling off by default you just add a line with the option you used in the `xinput` command after the "Driver" line, in this case `Option "NaturalScrolling" "off"`, so it would look like this:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput pointer catchall"
        MatchIsPointer "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
        Option "NaturalScrolling" "off"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput keyboard catchall"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
        Option "NaturalScrolling" "off"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
        Option "NaturalScrolling" "off"
EndSection
```

You can learn about other possible solutions and options here: [libinput - Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Libinput)

I do not know drawbacks from directly editing an existing config file, but if you are worried, you might just go for creating a custom .conf file next to "40-libinput.conf". The link above should have all info you need to do that.